# CoreData lossing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm facing a strange issue where core data entries are randomly disappearing after being saved to master context.

I have a multithreaded app with master, main and occasional private contexts that all are recursively saved. App also runs background location updates and significant location change updates. Data is mostly saved in background mode. Occasionally app is allowed to be terminated by turning location updates off.

When I save something to CoreData I am able to swipe away the app and reopen it without any data loss for hours. In my mind that should prove that all contexts are properly saved. But then after app sits in background for some time and is finally terminated, on next app launch data is often missing. Not always though.

On some devices I find it impossible to replicate but on others (usually 16gb iphones with little storage left) it happens quite often. Also it seems that turning everything off under Location Services>System Services somehow helps to trigger this issue.

Has anyone experienced smth similar?

Comment: It's not a lot to go on. Can you add details of what code runs when the problem occurs?

Comment: Does the saving behave correctly if you turn on UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend?

Comment: To my knowledge no code is running when problem occurs. I've put loggers around problem region that logs number of data entries and in applicationWillTerminate this number is correct. Then occasionally in next didFinishLaunchingWithOptions all data is lost. All saving is always done before location updates are turned off so this shouldn't be the case with finite length background execution task. UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend just terminates app whenever it moves to background and nothing is saved of course.

Comment: Also i've not observed any context save errors before this issue occurs.